# Почему schedule не выключается?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, schedule

Пиши телеграмм-бота и возникла такая проблема. Я использую shedule, чтобы каждые 10 секунд кидать сообщение юзеру:

```
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(get_sending_function,str(message.chat.id)).tag(str(message.chat.id))
```

Где message.chat.id - это просто айди определенного юзера. Я обращаюсь к функции:

```
def get_sending_function(chatId):
    bot.send_message(chatId, "ATTENTION! You didn't answer the questions!")
    for i in db.collection('users').document('ID').get().to_dict().items():
        if i[0] == str(chatId):
            mas = i[1]
            break
    if mas[0] == False:
    
        schedule.clear(chatId)
        return
    else:
        return 0
```

Здесь я через БД получаю значение в специальной графе и если оно False, то shedule должен перестать работать. Проблема в том, что после этого он делает еще одну отправку и только после этого перестает работать. Как это пофиксить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, я и впрямь не умный. У меня же просто send_message стоит не там...

```
def get_sending_function(chatId):
    for i in db.collection('users').document('ID').get().to_dict().items():
        if i[0] == str(chatId):
            mas = i[1]
            break
    if mas[0] == False:
    
        schedule.clear(chatId)
        return
    else:
        bot.send_message(chatId, "ATTENTION! You didn't answer the questions!")
        return 0
```